# Get the integer value of a level and add to new column

Tags: r, dataframe, levels, factors

I have a factored list of elements in a dataframe such as:

```
df <- data.frame("A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4), "B" = c("a", "c", "d", "b"))
```

I reordered the factor levels in column "B" using:

```
levels(df$B) <- factor(df$B, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

I would like to access the level of a factor. For instance I would like to get the integer value for the level of "b" (which would be 2).

**Additional Question:**

I would also like to add a new column to my dataframe that will give the integer value of the level. 
In the above example this would give:

```
df <- data.frame("A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4), "B" = c("a", "c", "d", "b"), "Levels" =c(1,3,4,2))
```

Comment: Your example is not correct. With the code you show, "b" is level 4. You need to use `levels(df$B) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")` for your second line of code to get your intended results.

Answer (score 4):

Method 1:

```
which(levels(df$B)=="b")
```

Method 2:

```
grep("b",levels(df$B))
```

Answer to additional question:

```
df <- cbind(df, "Levels" = as.numeric(df$B))
```

Comment: This works. Would you also know how I can add the results into a new column?

Answer (score 2):

`level_to_check <- 'b'; which(levels(df$B) == level_to_check) # 2`